# NSWindowFlipper build error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to use Mizage's [window flipper library](https://github.com/mizage/Flip-Animation) in my Mac app.

When I tried to build it, the following error occurs:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_kCAGravityCenter", referenced from:
  -[NSWindow(Flipper) flipWithArguments:] in NSWindowFlipper.o
"_CATransform3DMakeRotation", referenced from:
  -[NSWindow(Flipper) flipWithArguments:] in NSWindowFlipper.o
"_kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut", referenced from:
  -[NSWindow(Flipper) flipWithArguments:] in NSWindowFlipper.o
"_CATransform3DIdentity", referenced from:
  -[NSWindow(Flipper) flipWithArguments:] in NSWindowFlipper.o
"_CATransform3DRotate", referenced from:
  -[NSWindow(Flipper) flipWithArguments:] in NSWindowFlipper.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CALayer", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in NSWindowFlipper.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CABasicAnimation", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in NSWindowFlipper.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAMediaTimingFunction", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in NSWindowFlipper.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My base SDK is 10.7 and have ARC enabled. I am new to Cocoa and have not seen this kind of error before. Can someone suggest what's the problem here and possibly how to resolve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to link with the QuartzCore framework.

[**Linking to a Library or Framework**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010155-CH17-SW1)